# Tensor product is to flat as Hom is to ?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Sorry if I'm missing something here, but what do we call $M$ if the functor $H_M:N\mapsto Hom(M,N)$ is exact? Is this in fact equivalent to being flat through some adjointness properties?

Comment: Projective module?

Comment: Why the close votes? -- This is a 6-year-old question which has a highly-voted accepted answer. Of course it's just a question about definitions, which would likely be closed if asked nowadays, but anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We call such modules projective.  If you take $N\mapsto Hom(N,M)$ then you get injective modules.  This is fairly basic, and covered in any homological algebra book, and mentioned on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_functor).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'm still learning about tensor products from Atiyah-Macdonald, and I was just wondering what the analogous concept was :)

Comment: It's all there in Lang, I suppose. An advantage with a bigger algebra book is that you have everything in one place.

Answer (score 12):

It might also be helpful to know that projective is equivalent to being a summand of a free module (apply $Hom(M,\text{--})$ to a presentation of $M$), and hence projectives are flat.
The converse is not true in general (e.g. $\mathbb Q$ is flat as a $\mathbb Z$-module, but not projective), but for finitely presented modules over commutative rings, flat and projective are equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure that $M$ is called projective in this case, and if $N \rightarrow Hom(N,M)$ is exact then $M$ is called injective. I might have it backwards, though.